# Accurate localization through GPS, IMU and odometry

Tags: arduino, sensor, gps, robotics, accuracy

I am trying to localize a robot with an error <1m. I have XA1110 GPS but haven't tested it in an open area (due to the ongoing disaster) hence I am unaware of its practically achievable accuracy. I am also planning to fuse the obtained data with IMU and Odometry data through the Kalman Filter for better results.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone have any recommendations to optimize the approach?
2. Is this sensor enough to achieve the desired result or I need to upgrade?
3. Which one would be more suitable considering the budget (50$ USD), RTK or DGPS?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into differential GPS solutions? They can easily achieve the desired accuracy, IMU and odometry not required.

Comment: Yes but I am a bit confused between DGPS and RTK GPS after comparing their features and prices.

Comment: Differential GPS is the way to go. You can buy DGPS enabled solutions, or you can simply use ordinary GPS receivers and correct their positions in your own software. If you're confused between DGPS and RTK GPS, then **PUT THAT IN YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION** and don't waste our time, and your time, answering things you've already thought about. The more you tell us, the better answers you'll get.

Comment: I will roger that

Comment: If reliability matters, keep an eye on Notices to Mariners in your area, as GPS isn't always available, e.g. https://www.royalnavy.mod.uk/qhm/clyde/joint-warrior